# Reading the returned JSON string from a webservice in the .done method

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery

How can I read the returned JSON string in JQuery in the following code:

```
 var jqXHR = $.ajax(WEB_SERVICE + "createFolder?name=" + folder_name)
      .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR )  {
        alert(data ); // <--- I want to alert the returnd string
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
      }) 
      .always(function() {
        alert( "complete" );
      });
```

When I check the `data.childNodes[0].textContent` I get ""returned string"" -- with two quotes on each side. I want to get the string itself and use in in the .done method.

In the .NET webservice I use:

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new_folder_name);
```

To return a JSON string.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the service itself taking care of encoding? Try returning the "new_folder_name" as string without serializing to JSON yourself?

Comment: My main problem is with reading the value. I think that there might be an easier way to read it instead of what I did above

Comment: I don't see you reading the value in the code, except an alert? This seems to be a standard $.ajax structure?

Comment: The only way I find it to work is to read "data.childNodes[0].textContent" -- But I don't think that's the proper way to do it :[

Comment: Can you show us what the entire contents of data is upon done?

Comment: can you post your json string?

Comment: The return data is fine after I dropped the serialization (I get something like ("test_folder"). The problem is the best way to access the returned data.

Comment: have you tried accessing the data using `data.d`?